# How to syntax check php files in Travis CI?

Tags: php, bash, continuous-integration, syntax-error, travis-ci

I would want to run strict syntax check:

```
$ php -d error_reporting=32767 -l test.php
```

for all php files inside my project in Travis CI.

I tried to use **find** but it always just returns 0 even if the command for exec flag fails

```sh
$ find . -type f -name "*.php" -exec php -d error_reporting=32767 -l {} \;
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting ',' or ';' in ./test.php on line 3
$ echo $?
0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this by checking if the **find** + **php** returns anything into the STDERR.

```
before_script:
  - '! find . -type f -name "*.php" -exec php -d error_reporting=32767 -l {} \; 2>&1 >&- | grep "^"'
```

How does this work? Adding:

```
2>&1 >&-
```

after any command removes STDOUT and redirects STDERR to STDOUT.

Then we can just check if the output contains any lines with **grep**:

```
| grep "^"
```

Then because grep returns **0** if it finds anything and **1** if it doesn't find anything we need to negate the end result by using exclamation mark in the start of this command. Otherwise this command would fail when everything is okay and success when things are failing.